# .NET alternative for Access forms and reports with offline capablity

Tags: .net, database, ms-access-2007

A small company currently has an about 15-year old MS Access solution for stores, orders etc. (for comparison's sake, something like Northwind), developed and upgraded up to Access 2007. Now the original developer is no longer available, and is also completely unwilling to part with the source code (VBA) of all the custom reports, forms etc. in the Access application. Which means that I have to create a new application from scratch, and can only import the tables and data from the old Access, but no code at all.

Now having a C, Java, (ASP).NET C#, JavaScript/HTML background I really don't like VBA (please no discussion on that, it is just my personal opinion), I would really like to use some more .NET centric development instead of VBA in a new Access project.

My first thought was using LightSwitch, however the application also needs to work in offline mode. 90% of the work is being done in the LAN, with 3-5 clients just working with the .accdb file on the file server. Sometimes, one or two laptops need to copy the current accdb for business trips, and then use the local file offline (there is no way for them to connect to internet or intranet services). LightSwitch really doesn't offer a suitable offline mode without some major hacks along the way.

So far all the research I've done leads back to using Access again, as it really does work fine for the basic data entry, forms and reports, but I'd be really happy to hear about suitable alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using WPF or Silverlight?

Comment: yes, but that means having to do all the forms/report stuff that access provides by hand -- which is why I was looking at lightswitch that provides a lot of that plugging out of the box...